# Swift-конструктор с переменным числом аргументов

Tags: swift, objective-c

Вызываю из ObjC кода метод экземпляра `initWithParameters: (id)arg1, ...;`
В обжективе все работает хорошо, а вот в свифте вызывается только когда вызываешь просто `init()` без параметров. Пробовал создавать метод `init(withParameters: Any...)` и просто `init(parameters: Any...)`, но они не вызываются, а вызывается лишь метод `initWithParameters: (id)arg1, ...;` родительского ObjC-шного класса. Подскажите как победить все это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, в Obj-C и Swift несовместимые вариадики. в swift-файле прописал `@objc public init(parameters: Array<Any>)` и метод стал вызываться.

Upd: добавил как ответ.